# Pass simple parameter to unity Container

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, unity-container, containers

I have a key "MyKey" It can have a value "Key1" or "Key2".

Now i need to pass to container "MyKey" and value "Key1".

Can this be done without creating a Interface object in Container??

Any methods to go about.

```
 public class KeyMode:IKeyMode
{

        private string keyMode;
        public KeyMode(string keyMode)
        {
            this.keyMode= keyMode;

        }

        public string getKeyMode()
        {
            return keyMode;
        }



}


public interface IKeyMode
    {
        string getKeyMode();
    }


 KeyMode rcm = new KeyMode("key1");
                    container.RegisterInstance<IKeyMode>(rcm);
```

I have created IUnityContainer object "container" and a class KeyMode and a interface...I am creating Keymode object and registering value to container to pass.
Instead of KeyMode object creation. Is there a method to directly pass to container object in key value pair

Comment: Yes it can be done so. Post more code please.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like below you after.

```
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IKeyMode, KeyMode>(new InjectionConstructor("key1"));

        var keyMode = container.Resolve<IKeyMode>();
        Console.WriteLine(keyMode.GetKeyMode());
```

Comment: This doesnt solve my question ..I just want to pass key value pair without Interface IkeyMode and class KeyMode

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you meant by "key value pair". Your question doesn't indicate a key value pair. It just passing a single value/string into a constructor. Can you please update your question with more info! Either way, without an interface / instance type, I m not sure you can pass a key/val as such.  Probably adding bit more information would help to further clarification on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects at resolve time by using ResolverOverrides.  See [Resolving Objects by Using Overrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

Unity knows how to construct classes so you don't need to register the interface if you don't want to.  You could do something like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
KeyMode keyMode = container.Resolve<KeyMode>(
    new ParameterOverride("keyMode", "Key1"));
```